# How to use common sources for several projects (project dependencies)?

Tags: qt5

I have two projects: Server and Client (in two different folders) - two executable files at the output. But Server uses some sources from Client which are common for both of them. It is supposed that these two folders will be always in one folder, so relative paths are possible.
How can I tell Qt to use them?
I tried to add dependence to Server on Client in Dependencies menu of Project page. Tried to add paths to header and source of common files to *.pro files of Server (at HEADERS and SOURCES) files, but it didn't help (or I do something wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding common files to SOURCES and HEADERS sections should be enough.

Here's an example project:

```
my_project
|-- client.pro
|-- client
|   `-- main.cpp
|
|-- server.pro
|-- server
|   `-- main.cpp
|
`-- common
    |-- common_class.cpp
    `-- common_class.h
```

To both client and server projects use common sources you should and this to the both .pro files:

```
SOURCES += common/common_class.cpp
HEADERS += common/common_class.h
```